# How to retain previous changes using paint() and run() or other

Tags: java, user-interface, paint, runnable

how can I keep the previous changes using `repaint()` and `run()` or is there another solution for this.

I have this code running well. This code paints 3 ovals. When I put an input for the x-coordinate at the text box, it paints/draws the new oval. However, everytime I input and change the x-coordinate at the text box, the oval just relocates. What I want to do is to retain the previous changes that I have made. For example, I get 3 ovals at start when you hit the `see coordinates` button then you get 4 and so on after you input and click the `add coordinate` button.

Here's my code:
`/deleted/`

Any help would be much appreciated.

[EDIT]

I'm implementing K-nearest neighbors. So far what I have made are:
`1.created a gray panel of size 500x500 from (0,0)`

`2.gets file using browse button.`

`3.gets string and tokenize`

`4.token[0]= k-nearest, token[1]= total neighbors`

`5.token[2]= x-coordinate, token[3]= y-coordinate, token[4]= type of cluster and so on.`

`6.input x-coord and y-coord`

`7.compute distance between coordinates from txt file and input`

`8.draw shape according to minimum distance`

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Knn extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel grid,panel;
JLabel xlab,ylab;
JTextArea xtex,ytex,temp;
JButton cbut,fbut;
String text;
int k, ktotal, x, y,xcori,ycori;
String[] token;
int[] itoken;
boolean paint=false, paintclass=false;
double ans,xcord,ycord;
double[] dtoken,ansarray,xarray,yarray;
Map<Double, Double> anshash;

public Knn(){
    super("K-Nearest Neighbor");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600,500);
    //this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setLayout(null);

    grid= new JPanel();
    grid.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    grid.setBounds(0,0,500,500);

    panel= new JPanel();
    //panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBounds(500,0,100,100);

    temp= new JTextArea();

    xlab= new JLabel("X");
    xtex= new JTextArea("",1,7);
    ylab= new JLabel("Y");
    ytex= new JTextArea("",1,7);
    cbut= new JButton("classify");
    fbut= new JButton("Browse");
    panel.add(xlab);
    panel.add(xtex);
    panel.add(ylab);
    panel.add(ytex);
    panel.add(cbut);
    panel.add(fbut);

    this.add(grid);
    this.add(panel);

    fbut.addActionListener(this);
    cbut.addActionListener(this);
}

public double formula(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    double tmpans= Math.pow((x2-x1),2.0) + Math.pow((y2-y1),2.0);
    ans= Math.sqrt(tmpans);
    return ans;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    if(e.getSource()==fbut){        //choose file input coordinates
        JFileChooser fileChooser= new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                //output file content to text box, copy to a string
                temp.read( new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()),null);
                text= temp.getText();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        token = text.split("\\W+");
        itoken=new int[token.length];
        int i=0;
        for (String str : token){
            itoken[i++] = Integer.parseInt(str);    //convert from string to integer
        }

        for (i = 4; i < itoken.length; i += 3) {    //x50
            itoken[i-2]= itoken[i-2] * 50;
            itoken[i-1]= itoken[i-1] * 50;
        }

        paint=true;
        repaint();
    }
    if(e.getSource()==cbut){
        solveClass();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    if (paint) {
        for (int i = 4; i < itoken.length; i += 3) {
            x = itoken[i-2];
            y = itoken[i-1];
            if(itoken[i]==1)
                g.fillRect(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
            if(itoken[i]==2)
                g.fillOval(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
            if(itoken[i]==3)
                g.drawOval(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);
        }
    }
    if(paintclass){
        if(anshash.get(ansarray[0])==1)
            g.fillRect(xcori - 5, ycori - 5, 10, 10);
        if(anshash.get(ansarray[0])==2)
            g.fillOval(xcori - 5, ycori - 5, 10, 10);
        if(anshash.get(ansarray[0])==3)
            g.drawOval(xcori - 5, ycori - 5, 10, 10);
    }
}

public void solveClass(){
    String xcors= xtex.getText();
    String ycors= ytex.getText();

    dtoken=new double[itoken.length];
    xarray=new double[itoken[1]];
    yarray=new double[itoken[1]];
    ansarray=new double[itoken[1]];

    int j=0;
    for (String str : token)
            dtoken[j++] = Double.parseDouble(str);  //convert from string to double

    //convert to int
    xcori= Integer.parseInt(xcors);
    ycori= Integer.parseInt(ycors);

    //convert to double
    xcord= Double.parseDouble(xcors);
    ycord= Double.parseDouble(ycors);

    int q=0;
    for (int i = 3; i < itoken.length; i += 3) {
        xarray[q]= dtoken[i-1];
        yarray[q]= dtoken[i];
        q++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xarray.length; i ++)
        ansarray[i]= formula(xcord,ycord,xarray[i]*50,yarray[i]*50);    //x50

    anshash= new HashMap<Double,Double>();
    int r=0;
    for(int i = 4; i < itoken.length; i += 3){
        anshash.put(ansarray[r], dtoken[i]);
        r++;
    }

    Arrays.sort(ansarray);  //sort

    paintclass=true;
    repaint();

}


public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Knn knn= new Knn();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Here's the text file:

```
3 5 
1 2 1
4 3 2
7 5 2
6 9 3
5 5 1
```

Comment: I remember _this code_ ;-)

Comment: k-nearest neighbors is: gives you coordinates and the given coordinates have different classes(shapes) and when you input an x-coordinate and y-coordinate, it classifies what class the input should belong to by finding what given class is nearest to the input. after you have classified the input, the input must be saved and shall be used for next input and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> "However, everytime I input and change the x-coordinate at the text box, the oval just relocates. What I want to do is to retain the previous changes that I have made"

Use a `List` of ball objects. Here is the `Ball` class

```
public class Ball {
    int x;
    int y;
    public Ball(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void drawball(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Here is the `JPanel` class

```
public class BallPanel extends JPanel {
    private List<Ball> balls;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintCompoent(g);
        for (Ball ball: balls) {
            ball.drawBall(g);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic point is to keep a data structure of the ball locations. You may also want to have getters and setters for the x and y so you can manipulate their locations.

To add more balls, all you need to do is add to the `List` a `new Ball(...)` and call `repaint();`

---

Here's a running example. Just type in an `x` and a `y` less than 500 and click the button. You will see more balls being added. You can see in the `actionPerformed` where I add a `new Ball` and the in the `paintCompoent` where I loop though the ball `List`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestBall extends Frame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField enterX;
    private JTextField enterY;
    private JLabel labelX;
    private JLabel labelY;
    private JButton addBall;
    private List<Ball> balls;
    private BallPanel ballPanel;

    public TestBall() {
        balls = new ArrayList<>();
        ballPanel = new BallPanel();

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        labelX = new JLabel("Enter X");
        enterX = new JTextField(6);
        labelY = new JLabel("Enter Y");
        enterY = new JTextField(6);
        addBall = new JButton("Add Ball");
        addBall.addActionListener(TestBall.this);

        p1.add(labelX);
        p1.add(enterX);
        p1.add(labelY);
        p1.add(enterY);
        p1.add(addBall);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(ballPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(enterX.getText());
        int y = Integer.parseInt(enterY.getText());
        balls.add(new Ball(x, y));
        ballPanel.repaint();

    }

    public class BallPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Ball ball : balls) {
                ball.drawBall(g);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Ball {

        int x;
        int y;

        public Ball(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void drawBall(Graphics g) {
            g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestBall();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry if I used your code. well, all credits goes to you. btw, thanks bro, I learned a lot. Very well implemented. So I just have to override this.

Comment: However, can you help me more? The reason why I'm asking for all these help is that I'm implementing K-nearest neighbors. Can you take a look at my code. I've edited the above.

Comment: I don't get what you mean? I don't see your edited code. Am I'm unfamiliar with "K-nearest neightbors". Are you trying to animate? Is that what you mean by `run`?

Comment: Oh sorry. I just edited it now. I tried to get some from your code but I dont get results. Btw, k-nearest neighbors is: gives you coordinates and the given coordinates have different classes(shapes) and when you input an x-coordinate and y-coordinate, it classifies what class the input should belong to by finding what given class is nearest to the input.